# Check to see if a variable is decreasing

Tags: stata

I have the following variables in Stata: time in seconds and battery percentage. Is there a way to see if the battery is charging or discharging every second? Or just increased or decreased from the previous value?

Here is a made-up example of the data:

seconds battery_percent

1 54

2 54

3 55

4 55

5 56

6 56

7 56

8 56

9 55

10 55

Answer (score 0):

```
tsset seconds 

gen change = D.battery_percent
```

For more information see the help:

```
 help tsset

 help varlist
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: I agree a verbal explanation would be helpful. I would like to understand what each of those lines do and why they are necessary and how I may use this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Nick Cox is, per usual, the best way to accomplish this.

As requested by a few comments on his reponse, I will verbalize what he did, as it is really quite simple.

`tsset seconds`

This command is telling Stata to that you have time series data, and to interpret the variable "seconds" as the time variable for this data set.

`gen change = D.battery_percent`

Once you have your time variable set, this command will generate a new variable called "change" that will tell you the change in battery percentage at each second relative to the immediately proceeding second. Stata does this simply by computing the first derivative of the variable you list after `D.` with respect to your time variable that you set above with `tsset`.

Comment: I managed to suss out this but this is extremely helpful! Thank you so much. I didn't quite put together what D. meant. Thank you!!